# AVD instant crash with exit code 0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to get android studio running with an old project. I finally got past all the build errors coming from an old version of Android and eclipse. But now a new problem when I try to run it on the emulator, it just crashes right away! This even happens if I try to just launch the emulator without my app so I think it is a problem with the emulator itself?

> 4:13 PM   Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on
>   this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We
>   will address this in a future release.
>
> 4:13 PM   Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture
>
> 4:13 PM   Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for
>   use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
>
> 4:13 PM   Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without
>   DirectSoundCapture object
>
> 4:13 PM   Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without
>   DirectSoundCapture object
>
> 4:13 PM   Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
>
> 4:13 PM   Emulator: C:\Users\name
>   \AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe:
>   warning: opening audio input failed
>
> 4:13 PM   Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without
>   DirectSoundCapture object
>
> 4:13 PM   Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without
>   DirectSoundCapture object
>
> 4:13 PM   Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
>
> 4:13 PM   Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
>
> 4:13 PM   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

I have tried other device configurations with no luck... What should I do now?